# MVCGrid.net Table Fixed Header

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any possibility to use a fixed header in *MVCGrid* table? I tries many solutions, and non of them works well.  When in table are many columns, and user scroll these data to left side - header is going beyond the frame. I'm using a `StickyTableHeaders` *jQuery* plugin and the table structure is similar to `scrollable-div.html` in demo folder. I have a div contains another div with table, no styles but `overflow:auto` and `height:600px`;

**[Problem]**

[image]

**edit:**

[image]

**edit2:**

After "debugging"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to display 2 identical tables. Both of them belong to the same parent container that carries the "position:relative;overflow:auto;" style.

One table has the content, the other table has the following style:

```
position:absolute;
top:0; left:0;
height:32px; //this is your row height
overflow:hidden;
```

Next trap the onscroll event to the parent container. Synchronize the scrollLeft value to the left value of the fixed header table.

```
document.getElementById('container').onscroll=function(){
  var header=document.getElementById('header_table');
  var parent=document.getElementById('container');

  header.style.left=-1*parent.scrollLeft+'px';

}
```

Finally, (and this is an important step), put the parent container inside yet another container that has "overflow:hidden". This will clip off your header table, so that it stays "inside".

Edit: Try this snippet to see if the hovering header is at least clipped off. Your screenshot shows that the clipping isn't working.

```
<div style="padding:50px;">

<div style="overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="position:relative;">
    AA<br>BB
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:-5px;">
    XXXX
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

You can see that XXXX overlaps the AA but shifts to the left. XXXX is clipped off by the main container.

Comment: Two identical tables or just one table and second containing only header?

Comment: The column widths are not predictable as they are stretched by cell data. If you only display the header, the header columns will not align with the actual table. I know this is heavy but there is no efficient way to do this. I sometimes emulate the table with floating DIVs so that each column has a set width.

Comment: Darn. added some debugging code to see if you have some style override that's interfering